# Need to identify this web element (Drop down look alike) to interact with selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, drop-down-menu

I am automating some tasks using selenium (python) but I am not able to figure out how to interact with this drop down looking thing.

Below is the html code. Although it looks like a drop down in GUI but the html code does not look like it.

```html
<div class="Select lui-select lui-select-clearable has-value is-clearable is-searchable Select--single"><div class="Select-control">
  <div class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-2--value">
    <div class="Select-value">
      <span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-2--value-item">
        <span class="lui-select-value">
          <span class="lui-select-value-text">DummyName</span>
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;"><input name="projectManagerId" aria-activedescendant="react-select-2--value" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-owns="" role="combobox" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 5px;">
      <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 14px; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, &quot;Open Sans&quot;, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;">
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <span aria-label="Clear value" class="Select-clear-zone" title="Clear value">
   <span class="Select-clear">×</span>
   </span>
   <span class="Select-arrow-zone">
   <span class="Select-arrow"></span>
   </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a link of how the actual element looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp0dZ.png)

Can you please help me to figure out what actually is this item and how should I interact with it. I need to change the DummyName part to other items it the drop down list.

I have already tried interacting with it using select in selenium without much sucess

Comment: You need to do Mouse hover in selenium 
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement we1 = driver.findElement(By.id("-----"));
        actions.moveToElement(we1).perform();

Comment: _I have already tried interacting with it using select in selenium without much sucess_ where is your code and what are the error you getting? Please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly

Comment: I have also tried both using select and send keys method without much sucess.  When I use select I get error of 'element not interactable'  and when I use send.keys there is no error but nothing happens.  After spending some more time I realized that this is a react select element which needs to be handled differently .... I am still try to figure this out.